# Check a DIV for input item values are not empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've stacked some input text fields, drop downs, radio gruop inside a DIV. Now how do I check if all text fields, radio groups and dropdowns inside this DIV have some value?

I've created a simple mockup in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq3jL2d6/1/)

jQ:

```
$("#continue_btn").click(function(){
    if($('#myForm input:text[value=""]').length > 0){
      alert("yes");
    } else {
      alert("no")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to wrap your markup in a `form` element and to each `input` add attr `required`
this is pure css.

## [DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tq3jL2d6/7/)

```js
function highlight(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Done!!!');
    return false;

}

var highlightForm = document.querySelector("form#myForm");
highlightForm.addEventListener('submit',highlight , false);

/**
$("#continue_btn").click(function(){
    if($('#myForm input:text[value=""]').length > 0){
      alert("yes");
    } else {
      alert("no")
    }
}
*/
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="myF">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio1" value="option1" required></span>
          <input class="form-control" value="Fruits" autofocus required />
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio2" value="option2" required></span>
          <input class="form-control" value="Vegitables" required/>
    </div>         
  </div>    
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon quotationFields">City</span><input type="text" class="form-control numericOnly" id="weight_oq" name="weight_oq" required/>
        </div>
    
  <div class="input-group onlineQuoteForm">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Type </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="ptype_oq" required>
    <option value="">Please selelct</option>
      <option value="Satisfatory">Documents</option>
        <option value="val1">OPtion 1</option>
        <option value="val2">OPtion 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Continue"  id="continue_btn" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Now you can style it using this

```
input:required:focus { 

} 
input:required:hover { 

}
/**--------VALID----------*/
input[type="text"]:valid, 
input[type="name"]:valid, 
input[type="password"]:valid, 
input[type="email"]:valid { 

} 
input[type="text"]:valid:focus,
input[type="name"]:valid:focus, 
input[type="password"]:valid:focus, 
input[type="email"]:valid:focus { 

}
input[type="text"]:valid:hover,
input[type="name"]:valid:hover, 
input[type="password"]:valid:hover, 
input[type="email"]:valid:hover { 

}

/**---------INVALID---------*/
input[type="text"]:invalid, 
input[type="name"]:invalid, 
input[type="password"]:invalid, 
input[type="email"]:invalid { 

} 
input[type="text"]:invalid:focus,
input[type="name"]:invalid:focus, 
input[type="password"]:invalid:focus, 
input[type="email"]:invalid:focus { 

} 
input[type="text"]:invalid:hover,
input[type="name"]:invalid:hover, 
input[type="password"]:invalid:hover, 
input[type="email"]:invalid:hover { 

} 

/**---------REQUIRED---------*/
input[type="text"]:required,
input[type="name"]:required, 
input[type="password"]:required, 
input[type="email"]:required { 

} 

/**---------OPTIONAL---------*/
input[type="text"]:optional,
input[type="name"]:optional, 
input[type="password"]:optional, 
input[type="email"]:optional { 

} 
input[type="text"]:optional:focus,
input[type="name"]:optional:focus, 
input[type="password"]:optional:focus, 
input[type="email"]:optional:focus { 

} 
input[type="text"]:optional:hover,
input[type="name"]:optional:hover, 
input[type="password"]:optional:hover, 
input[type="email"]:optional:hover { 

}
```

Comment: Have you tested your demo? It doesn't check `select` and radio-buttons.

Comment: You just need to set the required-attribute to it that is all. let me update it

Comment: The question says that in jquery.

Comment: @Tambo even though text "DEMO ON JSFIDDLE" looks weird (too big letters, you know), it works correct now, +1.

Comment: @aM-Vee there is no need to over-complicate code and to use JS when problem can be handled with HTML and/or CSS. About custom validation text and so on - then probably jQuery Validation plugin will be more sufficient. I'm actually ready to vote answer, which validates correctly what OP wants using JS, but I haven't seen such answers yet.

Comment: Works perfectly Tabmo.

Comment: i added some css for UI

Comment: @Tambo, just saw it. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

The main difficulty here is radio buttons which you need to check separately. Try something like this:

```
var $form = $('#myForm');

$("#continue_btn").click(function () {

    var $radio = $form.find(':radio:checked');

    var hasEmpty = $.grep($form.serializeArray(), function(el) {
        return !$.trim(el.value);
    }).length || $radio.length == 0;

    if (hasEmpty) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no")
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tq3jL2d6/9/

Note, that for this demo I improved HTML a little:

1. wrapped everything with `form` tag, since you deal with form
2. added name attributes to all form elements
3. added placeholder attributes.

Comment: Thanks dfsq. But seems like your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me, maybe I misunderstand your scenario. It should alert "yes" until every field including radio buttons is filled in.

Comment: The alert is "Yes" in all conditions.

Comment: I think you don't fill in all the fields. Just to clarify: "Fruits", "Vegitables", "Weight" are not values, they are placeholders.

Comment: You've used `$form.serializeArray()`. How would you do if you want to split the input fields in to 2 sets? Can the class be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, here is the link

```
http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/
```

And here is the code

```
view-source:http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function which can filter every value in form like this

```
$("#continue_btn").click(function(){
   var anyFieldIsEmpty = $("#myForm input,select").filter(function() {
       return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
   }).length > 0;
   if(anyFieldIsEmpty){
      alert("yes");
   } else {
      alert("no")
   }
```

});

you can select multiple form elements like i have done input,select,textarea etc..

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tq3jL2d6/5/)

Comment: Doesn't check radio buttons.