# How to delete the div if all the input and select inside the div are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many div like below.

```
<div class="plsCheck">
<input type="text"value=""/>
<input type="text"value="" />
<select>
 <option value="1" selected>1</option>
 <option value="2" selected>2</option>
 <option value="3" selected>3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="PlsCheck">...</div>
<div class="PlsCheck">...</div>
```

I would like to delete the element if all input and select don't have value.
Jquery or just javascript is ok.
I tried to see the below post. but it seem the case is not the same.
[check-a-div-for-input-item-values-are-not-empty-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096463/check-a-div-for-input-item-values-are-not-empty-in-jquery)

I tried this but not ok.

```
$('.plsCheck').each(function(){
    var fillIn=false;
    $(this).find('select input').each(function(){if ($(this).value !='') fillIn=true;});
    if(!fillIn) $(this).remove();
});
```

finally, I tried the below code is ok. The key point is $(this) was change so I need to define a var to store $(this); second, fillIn need to be init after a div was checked.

```
var fillIn=false;
$('.item_type_group').each(function(){
    __this=$(this);
    $(this).find('select, input[type=text]').each(function(){if ($(this).val() !='') fillIn=true;});
    if(!fillIn) __this.remove();
    fillIn=false;
});
```

Comment: `I would like to delete the element ` which element do want to delete?

Comment: The title says you want to hide the div but the body of the question says you want to delete it.  Which is it?  Hide or delete?

Comment: how are people ever supposed to select it if its empty from the beginning, which would mean its hidden, and 'unselectable'

Comment: _"I would like to delete the element if all input and select don't have value"_ At page load ?,  within an `event` handler ?

Comment: Sorry, I revise the topic to be "delete"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but you haven't said *when*, or in response to *what*, the element should be deleted. Can you take the time to [edit] the question to explain, clearly, what your code does wrong (what doesn't it do that it should do, what does it do that it should not do)? For guidance, please read the "[ask]" guidelines, because your question is, currently, very vague and unclear, which means we can't help you, except by guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all your contribution.
since I think the solution I used have a little difference. I would like to post my solution here or you can view on my question.

```
var fillIn=false;
$('.plsCheck').each(function(){
    __this=$(this);
    $(this).find('select, input[type=text]').each(function(){if ($(this).val() !='') fillIn=true;});
    if(!fillIn) __this.remove();
    fillIn=false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you happy to just remove the div and all its contents from view if they have no value? If so, you need a function which will:

a. Check the state of the elements; then
b. Conditionally hide the div.

First, you'll need to give your elements ids so you can refer to them, and to give your select list a "select something" option, for example:

```
<div class="plsCheck">
  <input id="txt1" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="txt2" type="text" value="" />
  <select id="sel1">
    <option>--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I've also taken the liberty of making some minor corrections to your HTML.

Next, you'll need your function. I'll implement this in javascript so you'll know what's going on. Feel free to use a third-party javascript library if you wish to:

```
function checkDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById('plsCheck');
  var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
  var txt2 = document.getElementByid('txt2');
  var sel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
  if(txt1.value.length < 1 && txt2.value.length < 1 && sel1.selectedIndex < 1) {
    div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

Finally, you'll need to think about how your function is triggered. For example, you could have it triggered whenever the user changes their selection from your select list or changes the text in the text boxes, like this:

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" onchange="javascript:checkDiv();" />
<input id="txt2" type="text" onchange="javascript:checkDiv();" />
<select id="sel1" onchange="javascript:checkDiv();">
```

If you did this, then as soon as the user made changes which met the condition of (1) both text boxes are empty, and (2) no selection made from select list, then the div and its contents would disappear from the screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the event that should trigger this behavior, I'll just provide the code that will accomplish what you're looking for. **However, you do have to modify the `select` element; as it is it will always have one of the values: `1 or 2 or 3` ... so no div will be deleted.** Additionally, you want to have `selected` attribute on more than one `option` only when `select` has `multiple` attribute.

```
$('.plsCheck').filter(function() {
    return $('input,select', this).filter(function() {
        return !!this.value;
    })
    .length == 0;
})
.remove();
```

**Demo Using a Button Click as a Trigger**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#check').on('click', function() {
    $('.plsCheck').filter(function() {
      return $('input,select', this).filter(function() {
        return !!this.value;
      })
      .length == 0;
    })
    .remove();    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plsCheck">A
    <input type="text"value=""/>
    <input type="text"value="" />
    <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="plsCheck">B
    <input type="text"value=""/>
    <input type="text"value="" />
    <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="plsCheck">C
    <input type="text"value=""/>
    <input type="text"value="" />
    <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="plsCheck">D
    <input type="text"value=""/>
    <input type="text"value="" />
    <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="check">
Check
</button>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.plsCheck').each(function(index, obj){
    var fillIn=false;
    $(obj).find('select input').each(function(idx, elem){if ($(elem).value !='') fillIn=true;});
    if(!fillIn) $(obj).remove();
});
```

Basically, use $.each callback's second argument to get handle of the target element,

Comment: I like this solution the most. Thanks.

Comment: @KennethChan Selector `"select input"` selects `input` elements that are descendats of `select`, not both `select` and `input` elements. `.value` is property of `DOM` element, not jQuery object at `$(elem).value`

Comment: yes, the code should be `"select, input[type=text]"` instead.